# How to use the threads from a thread pool for every httprequest in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, httpclient

I need to create a thread pool of a fixed size and use the thread for every http request. Can anyone specify how to do this?

Thanks in advance

The code is

```
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpClient  httpClient =  new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    return httpResponse;
```

Here i need to use the thread from thread pool for every httpresponse

Comment: Does it mean you want to create a pool for httpClien object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Executors and pass your own Runnable which will process your httpResponse. Code snippet:

```
public class MyHttpResponseHandler implements Runnable {

    private HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

    public MyHttpResponseHandler(HttpResponse httpResponse){
        this.httpResponse = httpResponse;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do something with the httpResponse
    }
}

void processHttpResponse(){
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpClient  httpClient =  new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    executor.execute(new MyHttpResponseHandler(httpResponse));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create a `FixedThreadExecutor`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

then create a `Runnable` tasks
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html

and run them in the executor via `sumbit()` or `executeAll()` function
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Maybe you shoudl do the HttPRequest in the thread also. And mark this as an homework (it smells like one)